# Wrote 2 functions, don't understand what I did wrong

Tags: php

I've been practicing PHP more and more and am trying to do functions daily to learn from them.

Yesterday I wrote 2 functions but they completely didn't work and I was looking for help as to why!

My code:

```
<?php

function getFilesAndContent($path)
{
    $data[] = $fileData;

    $folderContents = new DirectoryIterator($path);

    foreach ($folderContents as $fileInfo) {
        if ($fileInfo->isDot()) {
            continue;
        }

        $fileData = [
            'file_name' => $fileInfo->getBasename(),
        ];

        if ($fileInfo->getExtension()) {
            $fileData['contents'] = getFileContents($fileInfo->getPathname());
        }

        $data = $fileData;
    }

    return $data;
}

function getFileContents($path)
{
    $names = file_get_contents($fileInfo->getPathname());

    $names = implode("\n", $names);

    sort($names);

    $contents = '';

    foreach ($names as $name) {
        $contents += $name . ' (' . strlen($name) . ')<br>';
    }

    return $contents;
}

foreach (getFilesAndContent('.') as $data) {
    echo $data['file_name'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $data['contents'];

    echo '<hr>';
}
```

DISLCAIMER: I really would like to get these 2 functions to work BUT I already have a working alternative(thank you very much!) without any functions, this is meant as a learning opportunity for myself to improve, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As it's a bit of guesswork as to what doesn't work, it looks like `$data = $fileData;` is overwriting the data, so should be `$data[] = $fileData;` in the first function and not sure if it should actually be `return $contents;` in the second.

Comment: Except there is only one Function in the code you show us

Comment: "They don't work" is rather useless to us. What are you expecting? What are you getting? What error messages do you get? Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `return $name;` should probably be `$contents` and `+=` should be `.=` because those are strings, not integers. Additionally the `file_get_contents` will give back a string, so `implode` won't happen. If you wanted the inverse `file` is a better function to use.

Comment: Sorry edited my code! Thank you for the explanations so far. My code is simply supposed to echo back the file name and then the contents of the .txt file. (in this case a small list of names)

Comment: Have you tried any of the changes suggested so far?

Comment: FYI, you can use `$names = file($path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`. The `file()` function returns an array of all the lines in the file.

Comment: Yes, updated my code with all your suggested solutions, thanks everyone! Right now I'm getting "Notice: Undefined variable: fileData in C:\xampp\htdocs\05-fix-me.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined variable: fileInfo in C:\xampp\htdocs\05-fix-me.php on line 30

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPathname() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\05-fix-me.php:30 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\05-fix-me.php(19): getFileContents('.\\04-data.json') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\05-fix-me.php(45): getFilesAndContent('.') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\05-fix-me.php on line 30"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems.

First, `$data = $fileData;` should be `$data[] = $fileData;`. Adding `[]` means that the assignment creates a new element in the array, rather than overwriting the entire variable. And when you initialize the variable at the beginning of `getFilesAndContent`, it should be `$data = [];`.

Second, `file_get_contents($fileInfo->getPathname())` should be `file_get_contents($path)`. `$fileInfo` is a variable in `getFilesAndContent`, not `getFileContents`.

Third, `implode()` should be `explode()`. `implode` joins an array to create a string, `explode()` splits up a string into an array.

```
function getFilesAndContent($path)
{
    $data = [];
    $folderContents = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    foreach ($folderContents as $fileInfo) {
        if ($fileInfo->isDot()) {
            continue;
        }
        $fileData = ['file_name' => $fileInfo->getBasename(),];
        if ($fileInfo->getExtension()) {
            $fileData['contents'] = getFileContents($fileInfo->getPathname());
        }
        $data[] = $fileData;
    }
    return $data;
}

function getFileContents($path)
{
    $names = file_get_contents($path);
    $names = explode("\n", $names);
    sort($names);
    $contents = '';
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        $contents += $name . ' (' . strlen($name) . ')<br>';
    }
    return $contents;
}

foreach (getFilesAndContent('.') as $data) {
    echo $data['file_name'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $data['contents'];
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you. I applied all your fixes and now I get:

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\opdracht.php on line 22

Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\opdracht.php on line 23

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\opdracht.php on line 25 

(part 1)

Comment: (part 2) Basically it's only supposed to read this .txt file with a small list of names in it and then display them. (With the rest showing the file name and that's about it and that's working as of now)
Originally I had: if ($fileInfo->getExtension() = '.Txt') but that didn't work.

Comment: `implode` should be `explode`.

Comment: Learning a lot from this!! Thank you very much! that did it.